# Getting the coordinates of the panel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, coordinates

Using mouseevents, I am able to get the x and y coordinates of the frame, yet I am unable to get the x and y coordinates of the panel. The below codes are me getting the x and y coordinates of the frame.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    text = Integer.toString(x) +","+Integer.toString(y);

    Frame.frame.repaint();

}
```

The below codes are me trying to get the x and y coordinates of the panel, but it's painting out 0's instead. Paint.paint is the name of my jpanel. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help if you can.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    x = Paint.paint.getX();
    y = Paint.paint.getY();
    text = Integer.toString(x) +","+Integer.toString(y);

    Frame.frame.repaint();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, your MouseListener is registered with the JFrame, and you wish to get the x/y relative to a JPanel contained within the JFrame. The x and y within the MouseEvent refer to the Component in which the MouseListener was registered. If you have a MouseListener registered on a Parent container, and which to get the coordinates of the MouseEvent relative to a child Component, you can using SwingUtilities to convert the coordinates

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    Point childCoordinate = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(parent, e.getPoint(), child);
}
```

Comment: Or I can just add the mouselistener to the panel, right? I did it, and it works. But I just have one more question. I added the mouselistener to both the frame, AND the panel, but now it's setting the coordinates for the panel instead. Not that I have a problem with that, but I'm just confuse as to why it sets it for the panel, when I add the mouselistener to both the jframe and the jpanel.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'setting the coordinates'. If both listeners set the value of the same variable, the one that is notified last will be the ultimate value.

Comment: so if i do frame.addMouseListener(event) and put panel.addMouseListener(event), it'll listen to the panel since panel is last. Okay. I see...